# Change variable value based on elemental position using :nth-child

Tags: jquery, absolute, dynamic-variables

I need to be able to have a variable that identifies that position of an `li`, using `.index()` and then assigns a value to it depending on the variable number for each individual `li`.

This may sound a little confusing, so I've written a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWCZq/) to explain it all a little better. There are 3 `li`s, and when I click a button/link, I need them all to spread out based on their `:nth-child` position, using `position: absolute`. However, the problem I have at the moment is that the variable (`itemNumber`) is the same and not changing for every `li`.

Here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum 1</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum 2</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum 3</li>
</ul>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
```

and JS:

```
var itemNumber = $("ul li").index() + 1;

 $("a").click(function () {
     $("ul").toggleClass("expanded");
     $("ul li").each(function () {
         $("ul li:nth-child(" + itemNumber + "n)").css("top", itemNumber * 30 + "px");
     });
 });
```

I'll be happy to explain it more because the idea is a little confusing. The basic premise is, I need the variable `itemNumber` to change for each `li`, and there could be any number of `li`s.

Comment: what should happen when you click on 'click me'?

Comment: The code only sets `itemNumber` once so the value is always `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$("ul li").each(function (index,element) {
         $("ul li:nth-child(" + index + "n)").css("top", index * 30 + "px");
});
```

Or better

```
$("ul li").each(function (index,element) {
         $(this).css("top", index * 30 + "px");
});
```

Comment: this worked great, thanks :) I added (index + 1) because index() is 0 based, so the first element is now 1. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.eq` instead:

```
var itemNumber = $("ul li").index(); // eq is 0 based index

$("ul li").each(function (i, v) {
         $("ul li").eq(itemNumber).css("top", (itemNumber + 1) * 30 + "px");
     });
```

Comment: this didn't quite work, it only worked for the first element. Not quite sure why, I updated the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TWCZq/2/ - with your code, and what it should do (Mohammad's code - http://jsfiddle.net/TWCZq/3/).